# Story identification: Runner stalked by avian alien

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a short story. A professional runner notices an unfamiliar face at the track. The newcomer keeps pace with him, then eventually beats him. Later he is running outdoors and is transported to another planet/dimension. The stranger he saw earlier tells him he is being hunted and gives him a weapon and a head start.

Comment: I'm reminded of Larry Niven's _What can you say about chocolate covered manhole covers_ but I'm sure that's not it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Came across this finally, I had some details off but it was "[Stride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Reed_%28author%29)" by Robert Reed.

Originally published in Aasimov's Science fiction (Asimov's Science Fiction, November 1994) and collected in The Dragons of Springplace;

[image]